# Text inside a blob using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I draw this picture in tikz. I did try it using hobby(tikz library) but I could not put any text inside this:
[image]

I have tried this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path[draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, fill=yellow!80] 
(0,0) .. (4,0) .. (4,4) .. (2.5,2) .. (0,0);


\path[draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, fill=blue!20]
(1,0.5) .. (3.5,0.5) .. (3.5,2.5) .. (2.5,1.5) .. (1, 0.5);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And this gives me the following:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to site. Please show us what you try so far, i.e. how you draw showed image.

Comment: Hi @Zarko, I have edited my question

Comment: You know the coodrinates used, just add a text node (`\node`) at the coordinate you want. Hint: it is a good idea to load the `calc` library as well, then you can do coordinate calculations.

Comment: @Anjan have  alook at the answer below --you can also write `\node at (current bounding box.center) {Q};`  -- plus you can do calculations with reference to the center anchor also

Comment: Thanks all. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With defining coordinates for curve with labels:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                hobby}
                
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every label/.append style = {inner sep=2ex, font=\sffamily\bfseries}
                        ]
\path   (3.5,2.5) coordinate[label=above right:A] (a)
        (2.5,1.5) coordinate[label=below right:B] (b);
%
\scoped[on background layer]
{
\path[draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, fill=yellow!80]
(0,0) .. (4,0) .. (4,4) .. (2.5,2) .. (0,0);
\path[draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, fill=blue!20]
(1,0.5) .. (3.5,0.5) .. (a) .. (b)  .. (1, 0.5);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,calc}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \path[draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, fill=yellow!80] 
        (0,0) .. (4,0) .. (4,4) .. (2.5,2) .. (0,0);

        
        \path[draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true, fill=blue!20]
        (1,0.5) .. (3.5,0.5) .. (3.5,2.5) .. (2.5,1.5) .. (1, 0.5);
        
        \node at ($(current bounding box)+(1cm,2cm)$) {Q};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Using

```
    \node at ($(current bounding box.center)+(0cm,0cm)$) {Q};
```

[image]